# C++ masking all characters of a string except for the last n characters with <algorithm>

Tags: c++, algorithm

In **C++**, how to mask all characters of string except last in character using `<algorithm>`?

ie;
I have a string

```
std::string barcode = "300001629197835714";
```

I would like to get output as

```
**************5714
```

This program can be easily done in a conventional way,

```
    std::string barcode = "300001629197835714";
    std::string out;
    for (int i=0;i<barcode.length();i++)
    {
        if (i<barcode.length()-4)
        {
            out+="*";
        }
        else
        {
            out+=barcode[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout<<out;
```

But can I do this with `std::replace_if` or with `std::transform` or any function from `<algorithm>` header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using the algorithm library and iterators. I'm using [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) to get an iterator 4 characters before `end()`, then [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) to replace the digits in the range `[begin, end - 4)` with `'*'`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string barcode = "300001629197835714";
    std::fill(barcode.begin(), std::prev(std::end(barcode), 4), '*');
    std::cout << barcode;
}
```

Note that

```
std::prev(std::end(barcode), 4)
```

will cause undefined behavior if `barcode` is less than 4 characters.

Comment: `std::fill` would be the fastest one, great!

Answer (score 2):

Neither `std::replace_if` nor `std::transform` is necessary. The simple

```
barcode.replace(0, barcode.size() - 4, barcode.size() - 4, '*');
std::cout << barcode;
```

Make sure `barcode.size()` is greater than 4.

[std::basic_string::replace (6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace).

Answer (score 1):

For string manipulation I usually revert to regex instead of algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string barcode = "300001629197835714";
    std::regex expression{ ".(?=.{4,}$)" };
    auto secret = std::regex_replace(barcode, expression, "*");
    std::cout << secret << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Regex is overkill here.

Comment: No. No overkill. Idiomatic correct solution. And by the way. The only correct solution, becuase all other answers destroy the orginal string . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny To copy an original string is far cheaper than use regex.

Comment: Overkill depends on the situation. For an arduino? Yes I wouldn't use this and it would indeed be overkill. In cases where say this has to run on a pc and it will be in a product I have to maintain for years... Yes I would use this, the reasons: Only optimize for speed/memory when really needed otherwise optimize for maintainability. Thus source code must be easily readable (so someone else may understand it too (or find publicly available information, like regex) and reuse as much existing and tested (!!!) code, which the standard library is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace_if` with a always `true` returning predicate and simply use the iterators from `begin()` to `end()-4`:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main()
 {

    std::string code = "1234564598745774";
    int numVisibleDigits = 4;
    std::replace_if(
        code.begin(),
        code.end()-numVisibleDigits,
        [](char){return true;},
        '*'
        );
    std::cout << code << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with `std::replace_if`

```
    std::string barcode = "300001629197835714";
    int nonMasklenght = 4;
    std::replace_if(barcode.begin(), barcode.end(), [&barcode, &nonMasklenght](const char &x)->bool {
                    size_t index = &x - &barcode[0];
                    return (index <( barcode.length() - nonMasklenght) );},
                    '*');
    std::cout<<barcode;
```

[ideone example](https://ideone.com/nOjbVC)

Comment: Or `barcode = std::string(barcode.length() - nonMasklenght, '*') + barcode.substr(barcode.length() - nonMasklenght);`

Answer (score 0):

IfI look at the original code of the OP, then we can clearly see that the original string should not be modified.

Only masked output should be shown.

So, nearly all answers, except from Pepijn Kramer, are wrong.

And by the way. A Modification is not required and is not necessary. Simply show the masked output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    // Our base data. It is const. It will not be modified
    const std::string barcode = "300001629197835714";

    // No algorithm and code
    // - - -

    // Just output
    std::cout << std::string(14, '*') << barcode.substr(barcode.length() - 4) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```